# Are all variables inside a static function static by default?

Tags: c++, static

```
static void Foo()
{
    int bar = 0;
}
```

Is *bar* static by default? What does Standard say about this?

Comment: No.  The variable is only static when you use the keyword.

Comment: A static function just makes a function 'local' so it cannot referenced by other objects. In other words, if this function was defined in foo.cc, bar.cc couldn't call that function.

Comment: This question is a proof that reusing the keyword `static` for hiding functions was a questionable idea. Perhaps, introducing a keyword `hidden` would have been a better approach.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Really all it's proof of is that the OP hasn't read his Stroustrup properly :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight This took me forever to sort out when going from C to C++: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/141897/98845

Answer (score 8):

No, the only provision for making a variable static in C++ is the [`static` keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static).

For example if you change `Foo` to:

```
static void Foo()
{
    int bar = 0;

    bar++;
    cout << bar << endl;
}
```

And then call:

```
Foo();
Foo();
```

Because `bar` is *not* static the output will be:

> 1
>   1

If however you declare `bar` as `static` like this:

```
static void Foo()
{
    static int bar = 0;

    bar++;
    cout << bar << endl;
}
```

Your output will in fact be:

> 1
>   2

Comment: Your print statements tripped me up for a second. I couldn't figure out why bar was equal to eleven :-)

Comment: @Evorlor Now that you say it that is kinda confusing. I've edited to add in an `endl`.

Answer (score 5):

No, variables inside static functions are allocated in automatic storage by default.

`static` functions and `static` variables represent orthogonal concepts that happen to reuse the same keyword in the syntax of C and C++

- Making a function `static` tells the compiler to hide it from functions defined in other translation units
- Making a variable `static` tells the compiler to place the data for that variable in a static storage.

Use of `static` for functions has nothing to do with static storage area.